# Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list

Tags: r, excel, plot, ggplot2, xlconnect

I am trying to plot 100 sheet of excel data that have different X and Y values. And, I am new to R, I just started using this a month ago. For now, I am trying to plot two sheets of data from the 100 sheets. I manage to use XLConnect to import the excel file onto R. And, string out the header from each sheets, so it doesn't mess up the format

And, I wrote this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
+     geom_line(data$Sheet1, aes(x=X, y=Y), colour = "blue")  
+     geom_line(data$Sheet100, aes(x=X, y=Y), colour = "red")
```

The R studio gives me this error message:

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list

So in the end I tried data with header and without header. Eventually, both all have the same error problem. I don't know what to do. Could you please help me out?

Thanks

**Update: the problem solved**

```
p <- ggplot(data$Sheet1, aes(x=X,y=Y)) + geom_point(color='blue')
p
p <- p + geom_point(data= data$Sheet2,aes(x=X,y=Y),color='red')
p
p <- p + geom_point(data= data$Sheet3,aes(x=X,y=Y),color='pink') 
p
```

and continue adding for layering the plot

Comment: You can provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).
Until then, try combining your data into one data frame.  You can `melt` or `unlist` lists to get them into data frames.  Also the code you gave has double plus signs `+ +` that could cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is a list then you have two issues. You should remove arguments from the ggplot call and then make sure you're explicit with the data argument in the geom_line calls. So, as a reproducible example:

```
x<-data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10)
data<-list(sheet1=x,sheet2=x)
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=data$sheet2, aes(a,b), size=3, color="red")+
  geom_line(data=data$sheet1, aes(a,b), color="yellow")
```

Comment: for the data.frame, I have data in x axis that goes from 0 to 15, and y axis goes from 0 to 100 range. So I put in this  
    x <- data.frame(a=1:15, b=1:100)
R seems have error on interpret these.